# Leadtools images stiching with overlap

Tags: c#, image, image-stitching, leadtools-sdk

We're developing system of getting combined image from camera, which being moved by step motors to make pictures of the whole area. The problem is that when we combine separate frames, the edges are not accurate because of step motors discretization. So we came up with idea to make frames with little overlap, so we can put them over each other to get continual image with no blanks. We're using c# + LeadTools. So I'm wondering is there any option in Lead Tools (or maybe some other sdk) to detect areas, which are equal on both images, so we can stitch them correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably find stitching coordinates using the [correlation command](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v18/dh/po/leadtools.imageprocessing.core~leadtools.imageprocessing.core.correlationcommand.html) of LEADTOOLS to compare the right edge of the left image to the left edge of the right image. The details depend on contents of images. Can you post a couple of typical images or email them to our support address?

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, looks like correlation command works ok for now. We're still waiting for testing images, I'll email them if we'll fail to stitch them in a correct manner.